# Misplaced \PropertyValue with xsim package using own exercise definition

Tags: xsim

I had to create a new definition for exercise with xsim package, because the hungarian heading text is reversed for the original. I did it as the manual shown, with only the necessary changes. Now the points, when used with property value, appears before the exercise text, as shown on the picture. [image: Exercise with misplaced point number]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xsim}
    \DeclareExerciseTranslation{magyar}{exercise}{feladat}
    \DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{magyar}{
        \subsection*
            {%
                \GetExerciseProperty{counter}.\nobreakspace%
                \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}%
                \IfInsideSolutionF
                    {%
                        \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}%
                            { {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
                    }%
            }
        \GetExerciseProperty{points}
            {
                \marginpar
                    {%
                        \IfInsideSolutionF{\rule{1.2em}{1pt}\slash}%
                        \GetExercisePropertyT{points}\printgoal{\PropertyValue}}%
                        \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{~ (+\printgoal{\PropertyValue})}%
                        ~\XSIMtranslate{point-abbr}%
                    }%
            }
    }
    {}
    \xsimsetup{
        exercise/name=\XSIMtranslate{exercise},
        exercise/within=section,
        exercise/template=magyar,
        exercise/the-counter=\arabic{exercise}
    }
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\title{Fizika feladatok}
\author{Benkó Tamás}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{exercise}[points=10]
    Miért ráz meg a bevásárlókocsi?
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task Mert a boltba lépéskor a kinti és a benti levegő összeütközik, és emiatt villámlani fog.
        \task Mert a cipőtalp és a bolt kövezete érintkezésekor elektromos töltések jelennek meg.
        \task Mert mágia van a levegőben, és néha túltöltődik vele, ami így ürül ki.
        \task Mert az embert felvillanyozza, hogy milyen új dolgokat vehet.
    \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Comment the line `\GetExerciseProperty{points}`
2. There is a missing `{` in `\GetExercisePropertyT{points}\printgoal{\PropertyValue}}%` just before `\printgoal`

%

**The entire code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xsim}
    \DeclareExerciseTranslation{magyar}{exercise}{feladat}
    \DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{magyar}{
        \subsection*
            {%
                \GetExerciseProperty{counter}.\nobreakspace%
                \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}%
                \IfInsideSolutionF
                    {%
                        \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}%
                            { {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
                    }%
            }
        %\GetExerciseProperty{points}
            {
                \marginpar
                    {%
                        \IfInsideSolutionF{\rule{1.2em}{1pt}\slash}%
                        \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{\printgoal{\PropertyValue}}% <----------------
                        \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{~ (+\printgoal{\PropertyValue})}%
                        ~\XSIMtranslate{point-abbr}%
                    }%
            }
    }
    {}
    \xsimsetup{
        exercise/name=\XSIMtranslate{exercise},
        exercise/within=section,
        exercise/template=magyar,
        exercise/the-counter=\arabic{exercise}
    }
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\title{Fizika feladatok}
\author{Benkó Tamás}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{exercise}[points=1]
    Miért ráz meg a bevásárlókocsi?
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task Mert a boltba lépéskor a kinti és a benti levegő összeütközik, és emiatt villámlani fog.
        \task Mert a cipőtalp és a bolt kövezete érintkezésekor elektromos töltések jelennek meg.
        \task Mert mágia van a levegőben, és néha túltöltődik vele, ami így ürül ki.
        \task Mert az embert felvillanyozza, hogy milyen új dolgokat vehet.
    \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]